# Count the number of queries from an application to mongodb

Tags: mongodb

I'm interested in counting how many roundtrips to the database from my web application I'm doing during the life of a query. Not counting connections, since they are pooled and reused, but actual queries (find, insert, update, ...)

Before I start adding profiling probes in my code, is there anything, driver side or server side, that could give this sort of information?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you should take a look at system profile in MongoDB. You can set it to log all database operations to a special collection withing MongoDB:

http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/manage-the-database-profiler/

> **Analyze Performance of Database Operations**
>
> The database profiler collects fine grained data about MongoDB write
>   operations, cursors, database commands on a running mongod instance.
>   You can enable profiling on a per-database or per-instance basis. The
>   profiling level is also configurable when enabling profiling.
>
> The database profiler writes all the data it collects to the
>   system.profile collection, which is a capped collection. See Database
>   Profiler Output for overview of the data in the system.profile
>   documents created by the profiler.

It does have some impact on performance, so I'd be careful anytime you are turning it on, but it's very useful when you are trying to determine exactly what's going on underneath the covers in your application. Particularly helpful when using a framework or ORM that may take a simple function call and produce large numbers of individual queries/updates/deletes.